# Graph a histogram or boxplot controlling bin width in seaborn or matplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have data that is already binned. I have a lot of bins (e.g. len(bins) = 100) with corresponding counts.

How can I visualize these bins, with the right labels? I am using seaborn and played with matplotlib, but I couldn't get the right layout. There must be a smipler way.

bins = [0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25...8.0]
counts = [600, 48, 57, 124, 170, 200,...77]

My code results in a black bar that covers my x axis labels (bins):

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
ax = sns.barplot(x="bins", y="count", data=df2)
```

Comment: Show what you get and what you want? If you want set bin width the same for all of them  use `width=5.` .